# Why can't I drop trading cards while playing TF2?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, steam-trading-cards

On a friend's Steam account, while he didn't drop a single TF2 trading card so far, the badge page says "No card drops remaining" for Team Fortress 2.  And indeed, we've been playing a few hours this week and he didn't get a single one.

He can't remember if he bought the game or if he's just playing the free to play version.  I suppose that's what makes the difference, but not sure.  Also, I don't know where I can find this information, nor how to resolve this "issue".

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119333/will-buying-items-from-the-mann-co-online-store-give-me-trading-cards?lq=1

Comment: Mhmm, actually, it's even a possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/119333/15726.  Thanks for the information.